# Twitter Login With Flutter issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am currently using twitter_login: ^4.0.1 for Twitter login in flutter with firebase and the following is my code

```
    import 'dart:developer';

    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

    import 'package:twitter_login/twitter_login.dart';

     class TwitterLoginController with ChangeNotifier {


    Future<void> signInWithTwitter() async {
//   Create a TwitterLogin instance
     final twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
     apiKey: "ImkA5qfZjykyVrR3o2OBDTKmG",
     apiSecretKey: "slY304BUP3FTC30WFFgo8xFnNc7ekF2KV4kinelWTZdFOLGIhI",
      redirectURI: "Doyen://",
       );

// Trigger the sign-in flow
        final authResult = await twitterLogin.login().then((value) {
  //    Create a credential from the access token
        final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
       accessToken: value.authToken.toString(),
       secret: value.authTokenSecret!,
        );

        FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
         log("this is test message");
        });
       return authResult;
       }
         }
```

But when I try to log in with the Twitter app is stuck on the screen which says "redirecting you back to the application. this may take a few moments". If anybody knows why it will be a great help.